# Вывод на страницу из разных таблиц базы

Tags: php, mysql

В базе MySQL есть 3 таблицы (TABLE1, TABLE2, TABLE3)

```
TABLE1

id(int)  group(int)  position(int)  type(int)  text(text)


TABLE2

id(int)  group(int)  position(int)  type(int)  text(text)  color(int)  comment(text)


TABLE3

id(int)  group(int)  position(int)  type(int)  text(text)  status(text)
```

У всех трех таблиц есть 2 одинаковых столбца: group(int) и position(int). Данные в этих столбцах могут быть одинаковые и разные.Задача сделать запрос к базе так, чтобы на странице вывести все строки из всех таблиц у которых: group(int) = 1 и предварительно отсортировав их по position(int).

type(int) - это тип блока в зависимости от вида таблицы. Потому что в таблицах разное количество столбцов, а значит при выводе должны быть разные html-шаблоны (для первой таблицы это 5 переменных будет вида

id: значение

group: значение

position: значение

type: значение

text: значение

- для второй таблицы - второй тип шаблона и уже 7, для 3й - 5 штук. И, насколько я понимаю, проверив через if какой тип - выбираем тип шаблона и подставляем туда эти значения и выводим (возможно это не так делается). И важно именно с сортировкой по position(int) чтобы вывести информацию.

Вот с такой задачей не могу справиться. Просто мозг сейчас взорвется. У меня немного другие названия, но я упростил всё для наглядности. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/S2Mst5NN попробуй так вначале

Comment: Да, это отлично работает и выводит данные из таблицы1 с учетом оформления. Но самое главное добавить сюда столбцы из двух других таблиц у которых $set="1" и отсортировать их все перед выводом по position

Comment: По этой же схеме можно собрать массивы из других таблиц и перед выводом упорядочить по position, но вот как это сделать я ума не приложу. Возможно ключ в том, что во всех таблицах первые 4 столбца одинаковые и можно это использовать, но у меня не выходит.

Comment: $result = array_merge ($arr1, $arr2);
print_r($result); Вариант?

Comment: да можно объединить массивы

Comment: array_unique посмотри ещё

Comment: В этом случае массив прогнать foreach и через if + type можно сделать вывод верстки под конкретный тип. А как в этом случае добавить сортировку общего массива или она автоматом происходит при объединении массивов?

Comment: array_unique Может что-то выкинуть, а мне нельзя)

Comment: прогони три таблицы выведи их отдельно на экран, можешь добавить '<td>'.$arr2[$tr]["color"].'<td>'.$arr2[$tr]["comment"].'   и закачай фотки  сюда https://ru.imgbb.com/ на словах не понятно что там сортировать по алфавиту чтоли

Comment: https://ibb.co/6H3hVw0

Comment: вот такой пример нашёл https://pastebin.com/L03vF8SX

Comment:  спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$conn1 = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* проверка соединения */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Не удалось подключиться: %s\n", $conn1->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$set="1";

$query1 = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE group = ".$set." ";

$result = $conn1->query($query1);
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$arr2[]=$row2;
}

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE group = ".$set." ";

$result2 = $conn1->query($query2);
while($row21 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
{
$arr3[]=$row21;
}

$query3 = "SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE group = ".$set." ";

$result3 = $conn1->query($query3);
while($row01 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3))
{
$arr4[]=$row01;
}

$result = array_merge ($arr2, $arr3, $arr4);
$row=count($result);

echo '<table border="1">';
for ($tr=0; $tr<$row; $tr++){
echo'<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$result[$tr]["id"].'<td>'.$result[$tr]["group"].'<td>'.$result[$tr]["position"].'<td>'.$result[$tr]["text"].'</td>';

echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: Немного не то. Самая концовка. Там должно быть if. Грубый пример: если position = 6, то echo “position 6”; и так далее, если  position 7 то другое, вот так перебрать нужно итоговый массив вот этот $result = array_merge ($arr2, $arr3, $arr4); это не получается сделать

Comment: ты сделал? выложи концовку сюда https://pastebin.com/

Comment: Что-то не получается у меня с этим.